# Best way to add the minus "-" front of decimal value

Tags: math, c#-3.0

I would like to ask how i should add the minus sign front of a decimal value.

i want the user to add e.g. 100 and behind the scenes to convert it in -100

thank you.

Answer (score 4):

What's wrong with

a = -a?

Comment: Maybe do this in an `if (a > 0)` block?

Comment: @always do you do arithmetics thru text? :)

Answer (score 1):

If it's a decimal, convert it to a decimal, and then multiple by literal `-1m`. Or what Pavel said.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply by -1.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about whether I got your question right. Are you asking how to negate a number?

```
decimal negated = -1.0M * userInputValue;
```

Is that what you are asking for? Or are you asking for automatically formatting the number as if the user had entered a negative number? In that case you could do:

```
string display = String.Format("-{0}", userInputValue);
```

I'm still not sure whether I get what you want...